# Check if arraytype column contains null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, null, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a column of arraytype that can contain integer values. If no values it will contain only one and it will be the null value

**Important**: note the column will not be null but an array with a single value; null

```
> val df: DataFrame  = Seq(("foo", Seq(Some(2), Some(3))), ("bar", Seq(None))).toDF("k", "v")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: string, v: array<int>]
> df.show()
+---+------+
|  k|     v|
+---+------+
|foo|[2, 3]|
|bar|[null]|
```

**Question**: I'd like to get the rows that have the null value.

---

What I have tried thus far:

```
> df.filter(array_contains(df("v"), 2)).show()
+---+------+
|  k|     v|
+---+------+
|foo|[2, 3]|
+---+------+
```

for null, it does not seem to work

```
> df.filter(array_contains(df("v"), null)).show()
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
> 'array_contains(`v`, NULL)' due to data type mismatch: Null typed
> values cannot be used as arguments;

or

```
> df.filter(array_contains(df("v"), None)).show()
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.None$
> None

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to use `array_contains` in this case because SQL `NULL` cannot be compared for equality.

You can use `udf` like this:

```
val contains_null = udf((xs: Seq[Integer]) => xs.contains(null))

df.where(contains_null($"v")).show

// +---+------+
// |  k|     v|
// +---+------+
// |bar|[null]|
```

Answer (score 9):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use the higher-order function [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#exists) instead of UDF:

```scala
df.where("exists(v, x -> x is null)").show

//+---+---+
//|  k|  v|
//+---+---+
//|bar| []|
//+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

The **PySpark implementation**, if needed:

```
contains_null = f.udf(lambda x: None in x, BooleanType())
df.filter(contains_null(f.col("v"))).show()
```

Comment: I think it's more efficient to avoid the UDF: `df.where(F.exists('v', lambda x: x.isNull()))`